# Does Global variable use more memory than local variables?

Tags: java, memory

In my code SonarLint suggests me to use local variables, but I want to understand if it's really the best practice to save memory.

Let's say I have the following class :

```
public class BufferedService {
   private BufferedImage firstImage;
   
   public void methodToUseVariable() {
      firstImage = ImageIO.read(new File());
   }
}
```

1. What Sonar Lint is suggesting is

   ```
   public class BufferedService {

   public void methodToUseVariable() {
      final BufferedImage firstImage = ImageIO.read(new File());
      // Something to do with firstImage...
   }
   ```

   }

Comment: In the second approach, the image object is eligible for garbage collection as soon as the method finishes. In the first one, it will be kept in memory as long as the `BufferedService` instance exists.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen by my understanding, I don't wanna reinitialize BufferedImage every time, so I'm trying to use only 1 instance until BufferedService is no longer needed but SonarLint was suggesting me to move it to local variable so I got curious, thanks

Comment: *"I don't wanna reinitialize BufferedImage every time"* This is the initialization part: `firstImage = ImageIO.read(new File());`, so you're doing that every time regardless.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen you are right, tnx for the clarification.